# SOQL to find out all active users that comes under the Profile = XYZ?

Tags: soql

just trying to understand whats the SOQL query to pull all active users from salesforce.

Comment: Take a look at [Salesforce Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/home).

Answer (score 2):

Your query could be as simple as:

```
SELECT Username FROM User WHERE IsActive = true AND Profile.Name = 'XYZ'
```